# How can I iterate over all elements in my generic list List<T> backwards and do the intended operation?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, priority-queue

I'm trying to create a Priority Queue and implement a function `deleteMax()` that removes the maximum element in the priority Queue. In order to do that, I've utilized the `sink()` method of the priority queue implementation and a `comparator` which compares two sets of values.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Lecture17<T> {
    private Comparator<T> cc;
    private List<T> myQueue;

    public Lecture17(Comparator<T> cc) {
        this.cc = cc;
        this.myQueue = new ArrayList<>();
        this.myQueue.add(0, null);
    }
    private boolean Smallerthan(int v, int w) {  // helper method to compare items to one another
        return (cc.compare(this.myQueue.get(v),this.myQueue.get(w))<0);
    }
    private void sink(int z) {
        while (2*z <=  this.myQueue.size()) {
            int j = 2*z;
            if ((j < this.myQueue.size()) && Smallerthan(j,j+1))
                j++;
            if (Smallerthan(j,z))
                break;
            swap(z,j);
        }
    }

    public T deleteMax() { // dequeues the highest priority item

        T highestPriorityItem = this.myQueue.get(1);
        this.myQueue.set(1,this.myQueue.get(this.myQueue.size()));// moves the last element to the top of the heap
        this.myQueue.set(this.myQueue.size(), null);              // to prevent loitering
        size()--;                                                 // update the size instance variable
        sink(1);                  // when heap order is violated, this will fix it

        return highestPriorityItem
        }
```

I'm trying to iterate from the top of the priority queue to the bottom for `deleteMax()` but I'm currently struggling to do so, can anyone please explain what I can do to find the smallest element in the priority Queue

Comment: If `myQueue` is ordered in ascending order you get the "lowest priority" element using `myQueue.get(myQueue.size() - 1)`. If you want to iterate backwards have a look at `myQueue.listIterator(myQueue.size())`.

Comment: can u show me where to edits specifically please? maybe in an answer or smth. thank u for ur response though but I can't seem to see where to put it in my code

Answer (score 0):

You're building a 1-based binary heap in a language that uses 0-based arrays. Whereas that's possible, you have to be careful about off-by-one errors.

In particular, you're using `myQueue.size()` to get the last element in the heap. But that's not the last element. Rather, it's the element *after* the last element.

Consider if you added the numbers 1, 2, and 3 to the heap. Your array will have the contents:

```
[0] - null
[1] - 1
[2] - 2
[3] - 3
```

But `myQueue.size()` is going to return `4`. So when this line is executed:

```
this.myQueue.set(1,this.myQueue.get(this.myQueue.size()))
```

It does, in effect, `myQueue[1] = myQueue[4]`.

That's not what you want. You want:

```
this.myQueue.set(1,this.myQueue.get(this.myQueue.size()-1))
```

And of course you'll need to change `this.myQueue.size()` to `this.myQueue.size()-1` in other places as appropriate.

Or, you can elect to actually use the 0th element in the queue. You just have to change your parent/child calculations:

```
parent index = i
left child = (2*i) + 1
right child = (2*i) + 2
```

And the corresponding:

```
parent index = left_child/2
parent index = (right_child-1)/2
```